# Who made the first high-wing jet airliner?

Tags: airliner, wing, aviation-history, jet

I thought the only high-wing jet airliners were made by the Soviets but the British Aerospace RJ-100 and Dash 6 series twizzled my mind.

So who made the first high-wing jet airliner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the Baade 152, built in Germany (GDR) in the late 1950s...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baade_152

Comment: Good find.  But if the criteria is airplanes that actually made into production, I'd say the 146 is it, at least in the West.